# Since ubuntu 22.04, anaconda-navigator launching errors : warning linux-scaling, Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE, libGL error

Tags: 22.04, qt, wayland, anaconda, conda

Here is my problem : I use jupyterlab across anaconda navigator. Everything was fine on Ubuntu 18 LTS. Since I updated Ubuntu 18 LTS to 22.04 LTS when I run anaconda-navigator in a terminal the following warnings appear on terminal screen

```
anaconda-navigator
2022-12-12 14:05:32,051 - WARNING linux_scaling.get_scaling_factor_using_dbus:44
Can't detect system scaling factor settings for primary monitor.

Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris: /usr/lib/dri/iris_dri.so: Ne peut ouvrir le fichier d'objet partagé: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: Ne peut ouvrir le fichier d'objet partagé: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Despite this warning error anaconda-navigator opens and runs. Then I can launch jupyter or jupyterlab using Firefox or chromium. However, jupyter-lab become sometimes very slow (it freezes) and very rarely crashes.

It seems to be a problem related to qt or wayland

I've been waiting for several weeks before posting this problem, thinking teams of conda, anaconda, qt project will find a solution to getting anaconda running well again but it seems the solution to this problem has not been solved yet.

If anybody have a solution to fix this Thanks in advance .